# Groovy script xml parser for multiple files

Tags: java, xml, groovy

Hi my groovy script strips out an xml tag from a file and writes to a file.

```
 import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
 import groovy.util.XmlSlurper



 inputFile = 'C:\\sample.xml'
 outputFile = 'C:\\ouput.txt'


 XMLTag='Details'

 fileContents = new File(inputFile).getText('UTF-8')

 def xmlFile=new XmlSlurper().parseText(fileContents)

 def myPayload= new String(xmlFile.'**'.find{node-> node.name() ==    XMLTag}   *.text().toString())


 file = new File(outputFile)
 w = file.newWriter() 
 w << myPayload.substring(1, myPayload.length()-1)
 w.close()
```

My question is how do I write it so the it goes through an entire directory and performs it on multiple xml files and creates multiple output as at the moment it is hard coded. ('C:\sample.xml' and 'C:\ouput.txt')

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you take what you have and put it into a single function; it's good coding practrice and improves readabililty.

Now to executing the function on each xml file in a directory, you can use groovy's [File.eachFileMatch()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch(groovy.io.FileType,%20java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)). For example, if you want to run it on each xml file in the current directory, you could do:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import static groovy.io.FileType.*

void stripTag(File inputFile, String outputFile) {
    def XMLTag='Details'

    fileContents = inputFile.getText('UTF-8')

    def xmlFile=new XmlSlurper().parseText(fileContents)

    def myPayload= new String(xmlFile.'**'.find{node-> node.name() == XMLTag}*.text().toString())


    def file = new File(outputFile)
    w = file.newWriter() 
    w << myPayload.substring(1, myPayload.length()-1)
    w.close()
}

// This will match all files in the current directory with the file extension .xml
new File(".").eachFileMatch(FILES, ~/.*\.xml/) { File input ->
    // Set the output file name to be <file_name>_out.txt
    // Change this as you need
    stripTag(input, input.name + "_out.txt")
}
```

If you want to, you can add reading in the directory from the command line as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Riley can't wait to try the new code quick question if my default folder for the xml files was say G://incoming_files would I change  to new File("G://incoming_files")?

Comment: that works thanks I am now trying to change the output folder of the output files to G://Outgoing_Files instead of the default directory is there a way to change directory in groovy?

Comment: @Leon Yep! You can add it in the call to stripTag 
`stripTag(input, "G://Outgoing_Files/" + input.name + "_out.txt")`
 or you can add it where the it creates the output file in stripTag 
`def file = new File ("G://Outgoing_Files/"  + outputFile)`

Comment: can i pick ur brains again i need to list all files in a directory and insert the file names into an oracle table im using 
String conceptsString = conceptList.join(',')
sql.execute("insert into LDS.FILES(FILENAME) values (?)", [conceptsString])

Comment: @Leon I'm pretty sure that you need to have to split the files up more for your insert. Try `String conceptsString = "(" + conceptList.join('),(') + ")"; sql.execute("insert into LDS.FILES(FILENAME) values ?", [conceptsString]) `. From this page [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert.html): "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas."